# Numpy check if time delta is negative

Tags: python, numpy, timedelta, dtype

I have an array of values that can be any type. When they are time-deltas, it causes a problem:

```
>>> d = np.diff(np.array([
...         '2022-10-13 10:00:00', '2022-10-13 10:30:00',
...         '2022-10-13 11:00:00', '2022-10-14 10:00:00',
...         '2022-10-13 23:00:00', '2022-10-14 00:00:00'
...     ], dtype='datetime64[ns]'))
>>> d
array([  1800000000000,   1800000000000,  82800000000000, -39600000000000,
         3600000000000], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
```

I want get a mask for the elements that are less than zero:

```
>>> d < 0
UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'less' input 0 from dtype('<m8[ns]') to dtype('<m8') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Since I want a general purpose solution that works for any dtype, I tried using `d[0]` as a template, also without luck:

```
>>> d < d.dtype(0)
TypeError: 'numpy.dtype[timedelta64]' object is not callable
```

The only way I've found to bypass this by constructing a special zero:

```
>>> if d.dtype.type == np.timedelta64: print(d < np.timedelta64(0, 'ns'))
[False False False  True False]
```

Is there a general purpose approach that will let me check when an array is negative that will work with time-deltas?

Comment: I get an even weirder error when trying `d < np.datetime64('0', 'ns')`.
`UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'less' input 0 from dtype('<m8[ns]') to dtype('<M8[ns]') with casting rule 'same_kind'` What is the difference between `m8` and `M8`?

Comment: @alec_djinn. That's because `d` is `timedelta64[ns]`, not `datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: Yes. True. Stupid me! But then `d < np.timedelta64('0')` does the trick. No?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html#numpy-sign).

```
np.sign(d)
```

Output:

```
array([ 1,  1,  1, -1,  1], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
```

Comment: The problem is that I still want the strictly negative ones, which means that I'll need to compare what is still a timedelta against zero. Still a nice trick though

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I almost had it:

```
>>> d < d.dtype.type(0)
array([False, False, False,  True, False])
```